# Restrict access of kvm guest to selected IPs

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have a kvm guest using nat (usermode networking). Because virsh in ubuntu 18.04 does not support netcf I cannot use nwfilter to control the traffic of the vm. 
How can I restrict the access of the vm to a set of IP adresses?

Mathias

Answer (score 0):

So for now I am using the [/etc/libvirt/hooks/network hook](https://libvirt.org/hooks.html): In this hook I dump the iptable-rules created by libvirt and look for the default forwarding rule for the bridge the vm is connected to. If the rule is there, it is replaced by a set of my restricted rules. If not, I assume the restricted rules are already in place.

This workaround works for me.